# Determine $\mathbb{E}|X|^p$ for all $p > -1$ when $X$ has a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \delta^2)$ (I am stuck with the integral).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

How to determine $\mathbb{E}|X|^p$ for all $p > -1$ when $X$ has a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \delta^2)$?

I know that:

$$\mathbb{E}|X|^p = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^p \cdot f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ where $f(x)$ is the probability density function of $X.$

The probability density function of $X$ is $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}$$ which is the density of the standard normal distribution.

$$\mathbb{E}|X|^p = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^{p} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^{p} \cdot e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\mathrm{d}x = $$

We put $z = \frac{-x^2}{2} \implies dz = -x \ dx \iff dx = \frac{dz}{-x}$ so we get:

$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0} x^{p-1} \cdot e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dz  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} \cdot e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dz =$$

$$= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi} } \left( x^{p-1} \cdot e^{ \frac{-x^2}{2} } \Big|_{-\infty}^{0} \right) -\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi} } \left( x^{p-1} \cdot e^{ \frac{-x^2}{2} } \Big|_{0}^{\infty} \right) = \ ?$$

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: If you are calculating $E|X|$ then it should just be $|x|$ inside the integral not $|x|^{p - 1}$

Comment: See similar question from same user, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703158/determine-mathbbexp-for-all-p-1-when-x-has-a-uniform-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the density for a $N(0,\delta^{2})$ variate?. Is it not $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})$ . Then what would be $E(|X|^{p})$? Would it not be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|^{p}f(x)\,dx$ ? . In particular what GEdgar has done is shown the moments for $N(0,1)$ variate. You can recover $N(0,\delta^{2})$ case by noting that if $X$ has $N(0,1)$ distribution then $\delta X$ has $N(0,\delta^{2})$ distribution.

Now you have that for a standard normal variate $X$,

$E(|X|^{p})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^{p} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\mathrm{d}x=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\mathrm{d}x$ .

Now substitute $\frac{x^{2}}{2}=z$ or $x=\sqrt{2z}$ to get that the above equals

$$2\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{2^{\frac{p}{2}}}{\sqrt{2z}}z^{\frac{p}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\mathrm{d}x=2^{\frac{p}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{\frac{p-1}{2}}e^{-z}\,dz$$

Now compare this to the definition of the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20gamma%20function,except%20the%20non%2Dpositive%20integers.) to get that

$$\frac{2^{\frac{p}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{p+1}{2})$$

Now these  are for the standard normal variate. To get for $N(0,\delta^{2})$ variate notice that if $X$ has standard normal distribution then $Z=\delta\cdot X$ has mean $0$ and variance $\delta^{2}$ and hence is $N(0,\delta^{2})$ distributed.

So $\displaystyle E(|Z|^{p})=E(|\delta X|^{p})=\delta^{p}E(|X|^{p})=\delta^{p} \frac{2^{\frac{p}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{p+1}{2})$ .

Comment: I wouldn't think of calculating $\delta X$ to be honest. Additionally Gamma Function doesn't feel intuitive to me since it's not real valued. Is there a way to check how $(E(|Z|^p))^{1/p}$ behaves when $p \to \infty$? I mean $\lim_{p \to \infty} \left( \delta^{p} \frac{2^{\frac{p}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{p+1}{2}) \right)^{1/p} $ @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Comment: I mean I am at a complete loss. What is it that you **ACTUALLY** want to ask?????. You keep going from one question to another. Then you make a statement like Gamma function is not real valued. What part of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a}e^{-x}\,dx$ look imaginary to you?Of course for imaginary arguments it will give imaginary values. Sin , cos all can take imaginary values, does that mean they are non-intuitive?. If you stop for a moment and actually read and meditate on a definition then only it can feel/ not feel intuitive to you .

Comment: Secondly, the Gamma function is one of the most used functions in probability. If you are taking a course on probability, then you will encounter the gamma distribution most certainly in the next few classes if not already so you better make sure IT IS intuitive to you.

Comment: @mathman12 Thirdly, Of course there are asymptotic results about the gamma function, perhaps the most useful among them is the Stirling's Approximation. Gamma function is THE generalization of factorial but for real arguments (and extendedly for complex arguments). So $\Gamma(x+1)\sim (\frac{x}{e})^{x}\sqrt{2\pi x}$ . Using this, you can compute asymptotic results like the one you asked.

Comment: @mathman12 Lastly , "I wouldn't think of calculating $δX$  to be honest" . What is this sentence supposed to mean? You yourself have asked about the p-th absolute moment of $N(0,\delta^{2})$ variate and I have given you the shortest way to calculate it. If you already have the moments of the standard Gaussian with you, then you can directly compute the moments of the $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ by just noting that $\sigma\cdot X$ has $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ distribution whenever $X$ has $N(0,1)$ (standard gaussian) distribution. So what you want to convey by that sentence is beyond me.

Comment: Ok, now I know everything. I was just looking through my book on probability and asking questions that took me to others. Basically, I needed to fill gaps in my understandig even to wrap my head around the article on Wikipedia (I needed the information about Stirling's Approximation). Moreover, I didn't treat my questions as "officially" - just thought about it as a dialogue as I didn't suppose somebody will actually write a full answer (I thought we could just talk in the comments without any concrete aim). @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Comment: @mathman12 talking in the comments without a concrete aim is not something that falls under the category of a "good question". If you want a detailed discussion, then there are many experts of the topics and teachers/educators. In this site,there's a feature of a chat room. You might even request an online meet to discuss. That by no means implies that you can ask a question and then proceed to edit it multiple times and change to a separate one and expect people to modify their answer everytime.

Comment: I usually just read my book, then look some things up in the Internet and when I can't find the answer that would fit directly my problem I ask in here. I don't expect that anybody will find my question interesting enough to even answer but if they do, then it helps a lot. Meanwhile, I try to work this out by myself, but sometimes, when I encounter something completely new (as it was this time) I don't even know where to start. I didn't want to offend anybody, I am sorry if my questions were not structured in a proper way. @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Comment: @mathman12 Also, you are asking about how to calculate the $p-th$ absolute moment of a normal distribution. Both mine and Edgar's answer aim at providing that. I am again telling you. Be speicific as to what you want. If you wanted a discussion, then you could have framed your question in that way. Every detail has to go in the body of the question and it should not be the case that we find them one by one in comments to already written answers. I strongly suggest you read through [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is **not an elementary function** (exception, $p$ is an integer).  You can answer in terms of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):
$$
2\,\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{x}^{p}{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}/2}
}}{\sqrt {2 \pi}}}\,{\rm d}x={\frac {1}{\sqrt {\pi}}{2}^{{
\rho/2}}\Gamma \left( {\frac {p}{2}}+{\frac{1}{2}}
 \right) }
$$

I did the case where $X$ has distribution $\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Comment: And how would that change for $\delta^2$? Could I somehow get your result from my calculations? Are those incorrect? How did you get your result? @GEdgar

Comment: See the link on the Gamma function.  Make a substitution to convert your integral to the definition shown there.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand it yet but I will try to make the substitution. Why do you take $2$ times the same integral? For odd $p$ the function under integral is not symmetric. @GEdgar

Comment: With the absolute value, $|x|^p$ is symmetric, even if $p$ is odd.  So $\int_{-\infty}^\infty = 2 \int_0^\infty$.

Comment: Ok. But that formula is correct, right? $\mathbb{E}|X|^p = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^{p} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\mathrm{d}x$ @GEdgar

Comment: @mathman12 Why would your formula be correct? you should really focus on understanding the definitions correctly . What is the density for a $N(0,\delta^{2})$ variate?. Is it not $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}$ . Then what would be $E(|X|^{p})$? Would it not be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|^{p}f(x)\,dx$ ? . In particular what GEdgar has done is shown the moments for $N(0,1)$ variate. You can recover $N(0,\delta^{2})$ case by noting that if $X$ has $N(0,1)$ distribution then $\delta X$ has $N(0,\delta^{2})$ distribution.